# Are you allowed to recite a verse from Tanach by heart while reviewing Mishnayos?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, tanach, mishna

According to those who hold that it is forbidden to recite a verse from Tanach by heart even for yourself, would it be permitted if  he is quoting it from a Mishnah while reviewing it by heart?

Comment: The Mishnah was not always written down and had to be reviewed from memory nor were books of chumash easily accessible as they are now

Comment: Do any mishnayot have complete pesukim in them? Not just a couple words and וכו'

Comment: @DoubleAA , there are of course many versions of _mishnayos_ and I don't know which are original, etc., but at least some versions of _Avos_ 4:1 contain entire _p'sukim_.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it might be interesting to look at a source relating to hakhel , where the king would read a portion,l from the Torah, then skip to somewhere else and say that section by heart. Perhaps this question is asked there.

Comment: @DoubleAA AFAICT Berachot 7:3 contains a full pasuk in all versions (incl. the Kaufmann manuscript).

Answer (score 0):

there is different psak on this so in mishna….

you can say it especially if it’s not from chumash and if you know the words by heart and you are just repeating it not for any purpose or to be מוציא someone else

but if you want to be machmir you are in company of many